# Xamarin Cross-platform template missing After Updating Xamarin

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.forms, cross-platform

[image: Xamarin new project image]

`BlankApp(Xamarin.form Portable)` and `BlankApp(Native shared)` are missing from New Project template list after updating Xamarin.

I also tried re installing Xamarin but nothing worked. (VS2015)

Comment: Have you tried the "Cross Platform App" template?  It sounds like it may have replaced the earlier templates, but should do the same thing.

Comment: Yes i did, its something different, its not shared and not portable.

Comment: A Forms app must use either a Shared or PCL.  Are you sure you chose the relevant options?  This bug discusses the change: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=51724

Comment: The new Cross Platform App project wizard lets you select blank app or master detail, PCL or shared, Forms or Native, and even lets you add Azure integration if you want. Are you seeing something different?

Comment: Yes, i can see the 2nd window now after repairing in which we can select weather we want to use blank app or detail, PCL or shared. Thanks for the help